# Computing the order of a group generated by three elements $a,b,c$ which satisfy the relations $a^2=b^3=c^4=1$ and $cbc^{-1}=a$.

Tags: group-theory

I have the following problem that I don't think I solved correctly. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

**Problem: A group $G$ is generated by three elements $a, b, c$ which satisfy the relations**
$$ a^2=b^3=c^4=1,$$
$$cbc^{-1}=a.$$
**What is the order of $G$ (There are several possible values for the order of $G$; find all such possible values**.

An attempt:

$$a^2 = cbc^{-1}cbc^{-1}=cb^2c^{-1} = 1.$$
This implies that $b^2=1$.  Since $b^3=1$ as well, $b=1$ since the order of $b$ has to divide both 2 and 3.  2 and 3 are relatively prime.\

So if $b=1$, then $cbc^{-1}=a$ implies $a=1$. So $a$ and $b$ are both the identity.

That leaves $c^4=1$.    The divisors of 4 are 1,2, and 4.  So if the order of $c$ is 1 then $G$ is the trivial group.  If the order of $c$ is 2 then $G$ is the $Z_2$, a group with two elements $1$ and $c$ with $c^2=1$.  If the order of $c$ is 4, then $G$ is the isomorphic to the cyclic group $Z_4$. It's an abelian group.

If $G$ is isomorphic to $Z_4$, then $G$ has two element of order 4, and element of order 2.

Comment: Trivial here, but it is always useful, when you have identified possible groups to make sure that all the relations are satisfied in the group you have specified - especially in more intricate examples. This can detect mistakes in computation.

Comment: It looks just fine to me. In fact, it may be a matter of convention. For some authors, to write  $\;c^4=1\;$ means that either the element $\;c\;$ is the trivial one or else its order is *exactly* four. But this doesn't seem to be a widespread usage.

Comment: It seems that the best option That G is of order 2., despite Don Antonio's good point  that typically, when given $x^n = 1$, it usually means that $x$ is of order n., But in this situation the only alternative seems to be that $G = \{1, c\}$ where $a, b = 1$, $c$ is of order two, and so $c^4 = (c^2)^2 = 1^1 = 1.$  I say this merely because of the fact that as you note if $|c| = 4$, we'd need either a, or b to be of order 4, yet your work shows this not to be the case.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback  Mark Bennet, DonAntonio, and amWhy!

Comment: @amWhy I don't understand the part "we'd need either $a$ or $b$ to be of order 4" in your comment.  What's wrong with a cyclic group of order 4, with $c$ being a generator, and with both $a$ and $b$ being the identity element? The group is generated by $a$, $b$, and $c$ (because it's generated by $c$), the defining relations are satisfied, and the OP's calculation shows that any other group with these properties is (isomorphic to) a quotient of this one.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Yes, of course, you're right; yet there would need to be another element (also generated by c: namely $c^2$ of order 2, and another element of order four, namely $c^3$.  I.e., $\{1, c, c^2, c^3 \}$, where $a= b= 1 = c^4$.  Thanks for commenting.  I had been assuming we had only $a, b, c, 1$, perhaps wrongly.